# How to share websocket connection between JS objects?

Tags: javascript, websocket

How do I share a websocket connection between different JS objects? I have a webpage that automatically connects to the socket on page load with a login-prompt. After the login is successful I'm hiding the login UI and making the application UI visible and loading a charting widget (tradingview) by passing my own datafeed in the widget constructor. The problem now is in the widget because it doesn't have a reference to the websocket and it doesn't seem that passing it as an argument is working.

NOTE: Just starting JS/Web Programming. Pointing me to the right direction is greatly appreciated.

wsfeed.js

```
var settings_symbols = {};
var webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/api');
webSocket.onmessage = function processMessage(evt)
{   
 var json = evt.data; 
 wsMsgHandler(json);
}

function wsMsgHandler(jsonResponse)
{
    jsonResponse = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);

    try
    {
        if(jsonResponse.length>0)
        {
            if(jsonResponse.API[0].event == "login")
            {
                if(jsonResponse.API[0].cmd=="settings" && jsonResponse.API[0].result=="success")
                {
                settings_symbols =jsonResponse.API[0].symbols;

                }
                doChartLoad(settings_symbols, webSocket);

            }
        }

    }catch(err)
    {


    }

}

function doChartLoad(settings_symbols, webSocket)
{
     var config = {
            debug:true,
            exchanges:["forex","stock","crypto"],
            symbols_types:[],
            supported_resolutions:[],
            supports_marks:false,
            supports_timescale_marks:false,
            supports_time:false,
            futures_regex:'/^(.+)([12]!|[FGHJKMNQUVXZ]\d{1,2})$/',
            }
            config.symbols=lstSymbols;

    new TradingView.widget({
        symbol: 'A',
        interval: 'D',
        timezone: "America/New_York",
        container_id: "tv_chart_container",
        locale: "ru",
        datafeed: new DatafeedEndpoint(config, webSocket),
        library_path: "charting_library/",
    });

}

class DatafeedEndpoint
{
    constructor(options, webSocket)
    {
    this.webSocket = webSocket;
    }
        onReady() {console.log("TV::onReady"); wsChartLoaded();}
        searchSymbols() {console.log("TV::searchSymbols");}
        resolveSymbol() {console.log("TV::resolveSymbol");}
        getBars() {console.log("TV::getBars");}
        subscribeBars() {console.log("TV::subscribeBars");}
        unsubscribeBars() {console.log("TV::unsubscribeBars");}

        wsChartLoaded()
        {
            try
            {
                this.webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({'cmd' : 'chart_loaded'}));

            }catch (err)
            {
                console.log(err.Name);          // ReferenceError
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see what is going on.

Comment: ReferenceError when wsChartLoaded() is called

Comment: You need something along the lines of a messaging center, with a queue of requests to send out, and a list of listeners waiting for incoming messages. The listeners should specify what types of messages they want to receive notifications about, and the incoming messages should hopefully indicate the type of the message

Comment: @ControlAltDel how do I accomplish this? That still sounds like DatefeedEndpoint needs a reference to another object-- which is my problem in the first place :D

Comment: `this` is probably not what you think it is.  Use the debugger to figure out what the problem is.